# Linux group ownership on symlinks - how to make default link group ownership the same as link target?

Tags: linux, symlink

I'm wondering what's going on with group permissions on symlinks that I have. There must be something I'm missing here. I'm seeing my symlink group ownership being a group other than the owner of the target or the directory the symlink and target live in.

For example:

I have this directory...

```
4 drwxr-xr-x      3 my_user group1   4096  Dec 18 15:40 my_files
```

And inside of it I have the following directory...

```
4 drwxr-xr-x      3 my_user group1   4096  Dec 18 15:45 my_link_target
```

If I create a symlink targeting my_link_target, the group defaults to the group 2 directories up in the tree...

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx      1 my_user some_other_group   19  Dec 18 15:46 my_symlink -> my_link_target
```

I created the link with: `ln -s my_link_target my_symlink`

Shouldn't the symlink take the group permissions from the target of the link? What am I missing here? How can I get the symlink to use the permissions of the target directory?

Comment: Why would it take the group from the target? It gets its group the same way any other file/directory creation does.

Comment: The group of the symlink isn't used for anything AFAIK.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the symlink take the group permissions from the target of the link?

No. A symlink is not connected to the file it points to in any way. The symlink just contains a pathname that may or may not exist, and it gets its owner group the same way all other files do (the creating process' primary group).

> How can I get the symlink to use the permissions of the target directory?

You can't. You can set the owner group with `chown -h`, but since the symlink is not connected to the target, changing one does not change the other, and they are not kept in sync in any way.